# Emacs cache save error with cedet

Tags: emacs, emacs23, cedet

Installed GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) and I'm getting constant save errors. The following line is repeated over and over again with maybe 30sec intervals.

```
byte-code: Beginning of buffer [6 times]  
Error Writing Table: #<semanticdb-table ctype.h> 
Save Error: "\"Error in macro \\\"name\\\"\"": /home/user/.emacs.d/semanticdb/!usr!include!semantic.cache
```

Any useful tips as to why or maybe even a solution? Stripped my .emacs only to the following 2 lines but the problems still persists

```
(global-ede-mode 1)
(semantic-mode 1)
```

Tried deleting the cached files under the /sematicsdb/ folder but still the error pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a macro somewhere in one of your header files that CEDET can't handle.  Newer versions of CEDET (the one from the bzr repository on cedet.sf.net) work around the problem first by fixing some macro parsing problems, and secondarily by ignoring those problems during a save.

The newer version of CEDET that doesn't come with Emacs has a different install than what is in Emacs, but it should still work if you follow the installation instructions (which excludes 'semantic-mode').

Comment: Hey Eric, I am facing the similar problem right now. Could you be more specific on this one? ***There is a macro somewhere in one of your header files that CEDET can't handle*** You meant in the .emacs config file or in the cpp source file? Thanks

Comment: I'm referring to C preprocessor macros.  Some of them get complex, and the resulting parsed data will fail to save, throwing an error.  Unfortunately, those broken macros don't get detected till save, making them hard to find.